# Maven Dependency Best Practice For Library Developers

Tags: java, maven

I'm in the process of developing a library that would be used to interact with an external service. This external service has its own library, but I'd like the users of my library to select the particular version to use at compile/run-time.

What's the best practice to ensure there are no version collisions when developing libraries? Should I specify the minimum version of the external service library in my POM and then if the client specifies a higher version it will be used because it's "nearest"?

For example the POM for my library may look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.external-library</groupId>
    <artifactId>external-library</artifactId>
    <version>${minimum-supported-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The client could then do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.my-library</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.external-library</groupId>
    <artifactId>external-library</artifactId>
    <version>${latest-supported-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: With some salt: use the latest version as dependency, so that will be loaded when the user had no prior dependency. For the rest rely on maven's version conflict resolution. Sometimes API jars exist (say only with interfaces). Those yield more stable dependencies. Or java SPI with dynamic detection of jars.

Comment: "Best practices" is a loaded term, rife with opinion-based possible answers, which generally aren't accepted on SO. Perhaps you should instead play around with it. Make a "client" project exactly as you outline above, see how things behave when the client chooses a different version of `external-library`. Make the choice yourself how you want it to behave.